# replace second occurrence before character regular expression

Tags: regex, replace

I am trying to find a regex pattern that would allow me to replace the first occurrence of .N. with .C. before the equal sign of a text as below

```
.C.CA._Z._Z._Z.$._T._X.N.IAI=M.
.C.IN1._Z._Z._Z.$._T._X.N.IAI=M
.C.D4P._T.F._Z.$._T._X.N.FUNC=M
.C.D4P.D.F._Z.$._T._X.N.IAI=M.N
.C.D43S.D.F5._Z.$._T._X.N.RS=M.
.T.C.D43S.D.F5._Z.$._T._X.N.RS=
.C.D43S.D.F5._Z.$._T._X.N.OWLEM
.C.D4P.P.F._Z.$._T._X.N.IAI=M.N
.C.D41.O.FLA.T.$._T._X.N.OWLEM.
.T.C.D41.R.FLA.T.$.X1._X.N.OWLE
.A.FA._T.F._Z.$._T._X.N.FUNC=M.
```

How can I specify this pattern?
Many thanks!

Comment: use this `\.N\.` regex and then replace the match with `.C.`

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Search regex:

```
^([^=\n]*?)\.N\.
```

Replace by:

```
$1.C.
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV5pQ9/3)

Make sure to use `g` (global) and `m` (multiline) flags.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. however, given that I have strings like this .N.#.%.S1.S1.T.C.CA._Z._Z._Z.$._T._X.N.IAI = M.N.# it actually selects the whole block (from N to N). I am interested in replacing only the first occurrence before the equal sign. is that possible?

Comment: @user3779916 you mean the one before `IAI` ?

Comment: @user3779916: I believe you just need to make it non-greedy. Check updated answer and new demo link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
([^=\n]*)\.N\.(?=[^=\n]*=)
```

Replace the matched `.N.` with `.C.`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bV5pQ9/2)